# Where are the names and locations of .class-files defined?

Tags: java, specifications, .class-file

The most upvoted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1654889/) suggests searching class-files with specific names in specific folders, as a workaround for reflecting anonymous inner classes. In which document (if any) are the names and locations of Java class-files specified?

The [VM-spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html) contains a detailed specification of the format of class-files, but there seems to be no specification of how they should be named and where they should be stored. Likewise, the [language-spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html) does not seem to touch on this subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the source code of the [Class class (getSimpleName method)](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Class.java.html) :

```
 1137           // According to JLS3 "Binary Compatibility" (13.1) the binary
 1138           // name of non-package classes (not top level) is the binary
 1139           // name of the immediately enclosing class followed by a '$' followed by:
 1140           // (for nested and inner classes): the simple name.
 1141           // (for local classes): 1 or more digits followed by the simple name.
 1142           // (for anonymous classes): 1 or more digits.
```

The mentioned document : [JLS3 "Binary Compatibility" (13.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1) states it like this (more precise but less concise) :

> Furthermore, the resulting class file must have certain properties. A
>   number of these properties are specifically chosen to support source
>   code transformations that preserve binary compatibility. The required
>   properties are:
>
> The class or interface must be named by its binary name, which must
>   meet the following constraints:
>
> The binary name of a top level type (§7.6) is its canonical name
>   (§6.7).
>
> The binary name of a member type (§8.5, §9.5) consists of the binary
>   name of its immediately enclosing type, followed by $, followed by the
>   simple name of the member.
>
> The binary name of a local class (§14.3) consists of the binary name
>   of its immediately enclosing type, followed by $, followed by a
>   non-empty sequence of digits, followed by the simple name of the local
>   class.
>
> The binary name of an anonymous class (§15.9.5) consists of the binary
>   name of its immediately enclosing type, followed by $, followed by a
>   non-empty sequence of digits.
>
> The binary name of a type variable declared by a generic class or
>   interface (§8.1.2, §9.1.2) is the binary name of its immediately
>   enclosing type, followed by $, followed by the simple name of the type
>   variable.
>
> The binary name of a type variable declared by a generic method
>   (§8.4.4) is the binary name of the type declaring the method, followed
>   by $, followed by the descriptor of the method as defined in The Java™
>   Virtual Machine Specification, Java SE 7 Edition, followed by $,
>   followed by the simple name of the type variable.
>
> The binary name of a type variable declared by a generic constructor
>   (§8.8.4) is the binary name of the type declaring the constructor,
>   followed by $, followed by the descriptor of the constructor as
>   defined in The Java™ Virtual Machine Specification, Java SE 7 Edition,
>   followed by $, followed by the simple name of the type variable.

So it can be said that the commonly known naming scheme **is** perfectly normalized and we can rely on it (as must rely all class loaders to find the necessary class files).

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that. These documents (the JLS I mean) are too damn long. For completeness, the text of the specification can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1).

Comment: I know. I gave up reading them and directly looked in the implementation for hints to the spec (I once had to make a specific class loader looking for inner classes for a very specific feature)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the naming scheme is not specified in the formal sense because it is (supposedly) an implementation detail.

Comment: But that could potentially render different implementations of the JVM incompatible. That doesn't suit the »write once, debu^H^H^H^Hrun anywhere« very well.