# How to get enclosed class?

Tags: java, java-8

I know `Class.getDeclaredClasses()` can obtains all the classes that it has declared but doesn't including anonymous classes.

I'd like to know is there a way to get all the enclosed classes via the enclosing class ? for example, I want to get the all enclosed classes defined in `Root` for test purpose.

```
class Root{
   void run(){
      Runnable task = new Runnable(){
         public void run(){}
      };

      task.getClass().getEnclosingClass();// return Root.class
      // but I want to get all enclosed class via Root.class, for example:
     // Root.class... == task.getClass() 
   }
}
```

the expected result is : `[class of task]`.

Comment: `task` is the name of a local variable, I do not think there is any way to get that. Or what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @luk2302 but `task` is defined in `Root`, and compiler will generates an additional class for the anonymous class.

Comment: Will `getDeclaredClasses()` do it? I haven't used it. Ah, no, apparently that's what you were asking about, but you left off the `es`

Comment: @DavidConrad `getDeclaredClasses()` return all declared classes  except anonymous classes.

Comment: What is your need, your use case? Could this possibly be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in disguise?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I start to kotlin [inline function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html). and I need to test that an inline function is inline to call-site function. so I need get all enclosed class to test that the call site function doesn't generates by compiler.

Comment: Looking over the API, I can't see any way to do it other than to guess at anonymous class names as in `Class.forName("Root$1")`, `Class.forName("Root$2")`, etc., but that's not a good way to go about it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks,sir. the idea look like fine. but I think it isn't for kotlin, just for test purpose.

Comment: @DavidConrad thanks, sir. I did that and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the naming scheme of your anonymous classes, you can try to load it with `Root`'s `ClassLoader`:

Naming scheme for javac is `<enclosing_class_name>$<anonymous_class_number>`:

```
Class<?> enclosing = Root.class;

try{
    Class<?> anon1 = enclosing.getClassLoader().loadClass(enclosing.getName() + "$1");
    System.out.println(anon1); // prints: class Root$1
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("no anonymous classes");
}
```

Comment: Note that while the naming scheme is specified, the actual number is not. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1 While unlikely, it would be legal for e.g. the numbers to be random or start at some number other than 1. So this works, but it doesn't necessarily have to work.

Comment: thank you sir.  I try it at once and close the question as soon as possible.

Comment: It might be better to use `findLoadedClass` instead of `loadClass`

Comment: @DavidConrad `loadClass` already does that.

Comment: @Radiodef You have a good point, I'm trying to think of ways to make this more robust, maybe inspect the class path and look for files that match the pattern :thinking:

Comment: Using the class path probably would be more robust. Using Guava, you could use [`ClassPath`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html) and do something like `ClassPath.from(Outer.class.getClassLoader()).getAllClasses().stream().filter(info -> info.getName().matches(Outer.class.getName() + "\\$[0-9]+")).map(ClassPath.ClassInfo::load).collect(toList())`.

Comment: @Radiodef excellent point about potential renaming that could happen. One example is de-sugared lambdas. At the moment it is `lambda$go$0` where `go` is a method where a particular lambda is declared; while it used to be `lambda$0`...